# Why question ban is not removing after editing the old questions properly?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

Currently I can't ask questions in my Stack Overflow account. So I followed the given instructions and edited my old posts. But still I can not ask questions on the site. Please can I know what should I do to avoid this question ban. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you undeleted and improved your previous questions?

Comment: Ultimately editing is only a means to an end, you need upvoted to escape the ban

Comment: @hims056 : No I didn't undeleted my old posts. I just modified the remaining posts. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try on them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleted posts still count towards the ban.

Simply deleting them means you cannot improve them and never get out of the ban.

Undelete and improve those posts. Get them upvoted and you will eventually get out of the ban.

Comment: I think this information should be extended and added to the FAQ entry, as at the moment it does not contain any information on how to retrieve deleted posts.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - Where do you see such information in my answer?

Comment: I meant the "undelete and also improve those" part, extended with a "how to undelete stuff, look at this". Bad wording on my part, sorry.

Comment: Thanks all who supported. I just checked my account. It has got some reputation score and the question band was removed.

Comment: @Su1 just be careful now, you are probably still at the edge of the ban. Think thrice before hitting submit button :)

Comment: @Mołot : Thanks for reminding. I thought all was over. I'll be careful before posting anything in stackoverflow. Because I learnt a lot from this site and got helped whenever there wasn't any resource to help. I'll try my best to contribute positively to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the best way to get out of the question ban is to write a lot of good answers. That's because writing answers gives you a "fresh start." It's a bit like fixing "bad credit:" Start paying your most recent bills on time, and the impact of past mistakes will fall by comparison.

Editing/improving old questions might work. But they are subject to "legacy" issues. Editing questions works best if the new versions draw upvotes. It might work against you if they draw new downvotes.

One thing I'm not sure of: If you change a lot of obviously low quality one-liners into whole paragraphs, will the system remove some of the stigma for very low quality posts? If I were writing the algorithm, I might program, "one liner plus downvotes equals very low quality." But that's just me, and I'm not at all sure that it reflects the site's priorities.